# Rating stars for the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, rating

I have been looking for a 5-Star rating control for a while now and have not found a solid solution.
This question:

[Anyone know whether there is a 5-star rating component on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292137/anyone-know-whether-there-is-a-5-star-rating-component-on-iphone)

Provided a couple of links to projects which are no longer available, and i have not been able to track them down.

Edit:  I am apparently bad at tracking down projects, but I think part of my question still stands.  Here is the updated link http://code.google.com/p/s7ratingview/downloads/detail?name=s7ratingview-basic-release.zip

So this questions is 2 part - Is there a solid premade solution out there, and could you direct me to it?

Is it better / fairly easy to (yes, i realize these two facets are in conflict) grow my own solution?  Could you give me some tips/resources to do so.  I understand the basic idea of subclassing UIView and tracking touch events to expand an image ontop of another image to look like stars, but a little more direction would be helpful.  I have been developing on the iphone for a little under a week and still need a bit of hand-holding.

Comment: This is still available: http://code.google.com/p/s7ratingview/downloads/detail?name=s7ratingview-basic-release.zip

Comment: Gah!  The link shows that as being an old project page, and the link it points to on github is a 404 >.<  Thanks for the new link!

Comment: You mean something like [`NSLevelIndicator`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLevelIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ?

Comment: Something like that yes.  However, is that available for the iPhone?

Comment: I've looked.  I don't think so... which is stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view) custom UIView with a 5-star rating.

---

[EDIT]

You can also try using [UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006798) and supplying a minimum/maximum track images.

Comment: This was a good tutorial for making these stars from scratch, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can give [DYRateView](https://github.com/dyang/DYRateView) a try.  I wanted to reuse the one in Ray's tutorial as much as possible, but there were several features missing from it, so I made one myself.

You can check out my blog for further details on how to use DYRateView in your project: http://iappexperience.com/post/23227218867/dyrateview-a-simple-yet-powerful-rating-control-for.

[image: picture]

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

Another way you may try [DLStarRating](https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating) lets you customize the area below the stars, detecting touches.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just Easy to Give a Star Follow this Code and Copy and Paste into Your Project and Simply Run.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    startview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 70, 230, 50)];
    startview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    NSInteger getrating = 0;
    int x = 5;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 5; k++)
    {
        UIImageView * mystarimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 5, 40, 40)];

        if (getrating >= k)
        {
            mystarimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            mystarimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gray-star.png"];
        }

        mystarimage.tag = k;
        mystarimage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [startview addSubview:mystarimage];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *letterTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(updateStar:)];
        rateMember = mystarimage.tag;
        NSLog(@"rateing %ld",(long)rateMember);
        letterTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [mystarimage addGestureRecognizer:letterTapRecognizer];
        x = x + 45;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:startview];
}

-(void)updateStar :(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIView *view = sender.view;
    NSLog(@"hello ji %ld", (long)view.tag);
    NSInteger getrating;

    switch (view.tag)
    {
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"press 1");
            rateMember = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"press 2");
            rateMember = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"press 3");
            rateMember = 3;
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"press 4");
            rateMember = 4;
            break;
        case 5:
            NSLog(@"press 4");
            rateMember = 5;
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"press 5");
            rateMember = 5;
            break;
    }

    getrating = rateMember;
    NSLog(@"Get rating -------> %ld",(long)getrating);
    int x = 5;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 5 ; k++)
    {
        UIImageView * mystarimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 5, 40, 40)];

        if (getrating >= k)
        {
            mystarimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            mystarimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gray-star.png"];
        }
        mystarimage.tag = k;
        mystarimage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [startview addSubview:mystarimage];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *letterTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(updateStar:)];
        letterTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [mystarimage addGestureRecognizer:letterTapRecognizer];
        x = x + 45;
    }
}
```