# Prompting the user to give a five star rating

Tags: ios, app-store, rating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rating stars for the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650175/rating-stars-for-the-iphone)

"Draw Something" uses a special screen to ask you to rate the app with five stars, which pops up after a certain amount of play.  The screen does not seem to use the usual AppStore process. It specifically gives you the option of five stars or cancelling.

Does anyone know how this is achieved?  I thought you could not do this programatically.

Comment: Sounds like a simple modal display.

Comment: You may want to look at iRate it handles ratings and might be of use for you [link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply, but I think you are missing my point - It ONLY gives you the choice of 5 stars and posts that to the AppStore.  All the app addins I have seen don't set the review to 5 stars right away.

Comment: if this was closed as an exact duplicate, why isn't there a link to where that duplicate question is? seems only appropriate to link to it

Comment: @OpenLearner The duplicate is right at the top there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't actually post the ratings from within the app (that would require them to know the user's iTunes password and it would also most certainly violate Apple's guidelines).

It's just clever wording that's supposed to suggest to the user that they couldn't post a 1-star review from the app, even though it probably just directs them to the App Store ratings page, where they could enter whatever they want.

Comment: MMmmm interesting point, I hadn't thought that it was socially engineered.  Deleting the app and redoing it to see how it does it.

Comment: Tested... awesome... yes, it doesn't force or default anything just clever social engineering.  ie. if you aren't going to give it a 5 then you would click the rating button.

Comment: THANKS HEAPS MAN this way bugging the hell out of me.

Comment: Ah yes, social engineering is the term I was looking for. :)