# How to change value of a custom adjustable control in XCTest UI Test?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

My iOS app has a 5-star rating view. How can I change the number of selected stars in my XCTest UI test.

[image]

This view implements *UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable* accessibility trait which allows users to change the number of stars by swiping up and down when "VoiceOver" setting is turned on in Settings > General > Accessibility.

I was wondering if I can use this accessibility feature in my UI tests to select the stars. Is there a way for a UI Test to send "accessibility increment/decrement" signals to the view? Is there any other way for me to change the number of selected stars in a UI test?

I tried using `swipeRight` and `swipeLeft` methods and they do interact with the view by changing the selected stars. The problem with that approach it is nondeterministic. When calling those swipe methods I do not know exactly how many stars will be selected and therefore I can not guarantee that my test will pass when it is run on devices with different screen sizes.

Is there a way for me to select the stars in this star rating control in an XCTest UI test?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`adjustToNormalisedSliderPosition`](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUIElement.html#//api/name/adjustToNormalizedSliderPosition:)?

If this doesn't work with the adjustable trait, you could try subclassing UISlider in your app, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650175/rating-stars-for-the-iphone). Writing a testable app is a big part of having solid quality processes.