# Control that would display an array of images - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

I'm wondering if there is an already existing control that I could give an array of images to and it would display them horizontally?

So in other words, if I wanted to show that something had 3/4 stars I could add 3 full stars and 1 empty star to the array, or if I had a list of 'options' that are represented by graphics (eg open late, BYOB) I could just add those elements to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) or a custom subclass based on it.

Comment: I think this is the way to do it, or if need be make my own control that is very similar.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe no - it's a too custom element. The closest that you can get is the UIImageView and its 2 images that you can swap between.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if there was an open source control that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check these out:

One answer [Anyone know whether there is a 5-star rating component on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292137/anyone-know-whether-there-is-a-5-star-rating-component-on-iphone/1205629#1205629)

Another answer [Anyone know whether there is a 5-star rating component on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292137/anyone-know-whether-there-is-a-5-star-rating-component-on-iphone/4667025#4667025)

Some googling:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view