# How to select all buttons when we select last button in ios

Tags: ios

Iam new to IOS programming,i have one doubt explained below:

I have 10 buttons as stars in the view,
If i click 10th button i need to show all buttons as selected.
If i click 5th button i need to show 5 buttons as selected.

I need this functionality to give rating in my ios app.

Please can anyone suggest me the solution for my question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know whether there is a 5-star rating component on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292137/anyone-know-whether-there-is-a-5-star-rating-component-on-iphone)

Comment: Show us code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If I have to do this then I will give this button row an incremented tag from 1 to 10, then if someone press the 5 button i will get its tag and using loop change the button images from 1 to 5 getting the object of button using tag.

like you have selector for all button

```
-(void)userRatingAction:(id)sender {
UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
for(int index = 1; index <= button.tag; index++) {
    UIButton* ratingButton = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:index];
    // set the button image here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer with the help of below link http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/demos/Ext.List.select/

Answer (score 0):

Use of `Tag` property can solve the problem.

Assign tag to all the UIButtons you have starting from 1-10. Create a common `IBAction` and on action..

```
-(IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender{
    UIButton *selectedBtn=(UIButton *)sender;

    //First Reset all the selection
    for(UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews){
        if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
             if(btn.tag>=1 && btn.tag<=10){
                 btn.selected=NO;
             }
        }
    }

    //Now Select

    for(UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews){
        if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
             if(btn.tag>=1 && btn.tag<=selectedBtn.tag){
                 btn.selected=YES;
             }
        }
    }

}
```

Thats it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To draw star buttons -

make imgArr global nsmutable array to store button objects

```
imgArr  =   [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
float   leftMargin  =   10;
float   topMargin   =   50;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    UIButton *starBtn  =   [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftMargin, topMargin, 25, 25)];
    [starBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [starBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [starBtn setTag:i+1];

    [starBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [starBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(starBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:starBtn];
    [imgArr addObject:starBtn];
    leftMargin  +=  35;
```

}

```
-(void)starBtnClicked:(UIButton *)tempBtn{
    NSLog(@"TEMP BTN CLICKED :: %@",tempBtn.titleLabel.text);
    for (int i=0; i<imgArr.count; i++) {
        UIButton *btn   =   (UIButton *)[imgArr objectAtIndex:i];
        if(i < tempBtn.tag){
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_full.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to do so follow these steps.

Step 1 - From xib set tag of all buttons sequentially in incremented order. (e.g. 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110)

Step 2 - Write following code in your .m file.

```
-(IBAction)rattingsButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    int currentTag = [sender tag];

    for (int index = 101; index <= 110; index++) {

        if ([[self.view viewWithTag:index] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:index];

            if (button.tag <= currentTag) {
                button.selected  = YES;

            } else {
                button.selected  = NO;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3 - set IBAction - UITouchupInside to above methods.

you are all set, Compile and check code.